# Getting error as mentioned below

Tags: java, selenium

Hi I am trying to test logging into bookmyshow.

Firstly I am reading data  from excel sheet to write in username and password but while executing I am getting *error* that

> **Error: Main method not found in class Test_Pack1.Bookmyshow, please
>   define the main method as:    public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend
>   javafx.application.Application**.

I am providing written program code as well.please look into this and correct me if I am wrong thank you.

```
package Test_Pack1;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;


public class Bookmyshow {

    //public static void main()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                 "G:\\Selenium_Test\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://in.bookmyshow.com/hyderabad?wzrk_source=Google&wzrk_medium=CPC_Branded&wzrk_campaign=Book_My_Show_Search|RLSA&gclid=CjwKEAiAu6DBBRDDr6-e_6698E0SJACvuxnyBrs85Juwsx_cWiHXrPnS0eKFhZoQmo_nCYgopyDSIxoCGCHw_wcB");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement((By.className("email-input")));
//      driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iUserName']")).notifyAll();

    }

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
       {
           FileInputStream istream=new      FileInputStream("G:\\Selenium_Test\\hari.xlsx");
           XSSFWorkbook wrkbook=new XSSFWorkbook(istream);
           XSSFSheet sheet1=wrkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
           XSSFRow row=null;
           XSSFCell cell=null;

           HashMap<String, String> dataHmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
           String PropertyName,value;
           int lastRowNumber=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have commented earlier section is not correct.

First of all, your code which needs to be invoked as a starting point should be included in `main method`.You can invoke multiple methods in turn from inside `main method`. I have tried to change your code bit and it should work. Let me know if you face any issue further

```
package com.automation.servicenow.config;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;


public class Bookmyshow  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                 "G:\\Selenium_Test\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://in.bookmyshow.com/hyderabad?wzrk_source=Google&wzrk_medium=CPC_Branded&wzrk_campaign=Book_My_Show_Search|RLSA&gclid=CjwKEAiAu6DBBRDDr6-e_6698E0SJACvuxnyBrs85Juwsx_cWiHXrPnS0eKFhZoQmo_nCYgopyDSIxoCGCHw_wcB");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement((By.className("email-input")));
//      driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName"));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='iUserName']")).notifyAll();

        FileInputStream istream=new FileInputStream("G:\\Selenium_Test\\hari.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wrkbook=new XSSFWorkbook(istream);
        XSSFSheet sheet1=wrkbook.getSheet("Sheet1");
        XSSFRow row=null;
        XSSFCell cell=null;

        HashMap<String, String> dataHmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String PropertyName,value;
        int lastRowNumber=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for reply.

Still The problem hasn't resolved.I tried as per ur comments before.

Now I am getting error as "Error: Main method not found in class Test_Pack1.Bookmyshow, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
".Please suggest me how to resolve this problem.

For what reason these type of errors will come.